# How to show the result of webservice in tabhost on android/eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, android-tabhost

I need to show the "result" in tabhost,(which result is from consuming the webservice).
How to do this?

thanks a lot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear enough.

Tabhost is a container and usually we put some activities in it. So when you got result from webservice, you could put result into activities.